# MudBlazor: Cannot update the index of all DropItems in a MudDropContainer when rearranging the order

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

When dragging a MudListItem up or down in a List only the item being dragged triggers the `ItemUpdated (MudItemDropInfo<DropItem> dropItem)` procedure. So if the item is being dragged from position 1 to position 0 the items index changes to 0 however the item it was dragged over stays at index 0.

If I rearrange the order and then drag and drop each item onto itself then the index is updated. Is there a way I can trigger the update in code?

Thank you

```
    private void ItemUpdated(MudItemDropInfo<DropItem> dropItem)
    {
        dropItem.Item.Selector = dropItem.DropzoneIdentifier;
        dropItem.Item.Index = dropItem.IndexInZone;
    }
```

Comment: Please share your MudDrop component and all relevant code. Even better if you can set up the snippet environment with your problem. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet